# How to use multiple assert in a test

Tags: assert, coded-ui-tests

I have to work on a HTML page and verify the result (adding some texts, selecting some items from comboboxes, clicking on some button).

For example action1, action2 and action3.

After each action, I need to verify the result of the previous action. In QTP, we would use Report.Fail (Pass, warning) and go to the next action.

Here in code UI, I'm using something like

```
try{
  Action1;
  Assert //some kind of assert
  Action2;
  Assert //some kind of assert
  Action3;
  Assert //some kind of assert
}
Catch (exception ex)
{
  ...
  Assert.Fail()
}
```

This works somehow but not perfect. The problem is, if I remove the `Assert.Fail` from `catch`, the test will be passed! Which is odd (even the previous assert caused to get into catch statement). On the other hand, If I keep the `assert.fail` in the catch statement, the test will fail, but the screen capture is not the right one (the screen capture will be taken by `assert.fail` but not the previous ones).

So **my 1st question** is how can I use multiple asserts and if one of them fails, close the test in right way and mark the test as Failed?

my **2nd question** is, is it possible to make a logical operation with assert? Lets assume that we have a condition which can be A or B (depending or run time case). Now how should I check with the assert the conditions? It should pass the test only, if the condition is A or B. In all other cases the test should fail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Coded UI framework code calls methods with a [TestMethod] attribute. Inside the test method an **assert** is called to report a test failure, the `Assert` throws an exception that the framework catches. That framework save an image after it catches the exception. If your code catches the exception then the failure is not passed to the framework. If your code catches several exceptions from different asserts in your test then the framework will not see those exceptions. Hence the behavior you see.

Coded UI generally works on the basis of stopping the test at the first condition (ie the first assertion) that fails. If you want a test to check multiple items and report all of them that fail then you need to code that yourself. Commonly you change the assert calls to simple `if` tests and, if the test fails record why, then near the end of the test check whether any of the tests failed. If they did then call `Assert.Fail` and pass a summary of the failure reasons.

For getting screen images from the points of failure you can use a mixture of these types of statement:

```
Image img1 = UITestControl.Desktop.CaptureImage();
Image img2 = this.UIMap.UIYourApplicationsWindow.CaptureImage();
Image img3 = this.UIMap.UIYourApplicationsWindow.UISubWindow.UISubSub.CaptureImage();
... followed by:
imgX.Save( ... filename ... ); // For various X
TextContext.AddResultFile(... filename ... )
```

The `img.Save` calls will create a file for each call including calls from tests that pass. The `AddResultFile` makes copies of those files for tests that fail.

Comment: I followed your instruction and removed try/catch in order to let the framework to catch the error and fail. However the errors cause a run time exception because I don't catch them. So it is not a nice way to report a failed case. Hence I think, I need to have try/catch. Am I doing wrong? or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @user2585405 what do you mean by "the errors cause a run time exception"? That is the purpose of an assert, then in Coded UI the framework catches those exceptions to indicate test failures. Suppose you use a try catch then how would you signal test failures to the framework? Try using the Coded UI record and generate tool to make a very simple test of (eg) the Windows Calculator, include a recorded assertion then modify the values to make it fail. Run the test and see how Coded UI handles errors.

Comment: Lets assume that an object which you refers in your test, doesn't exist for some reason at run time and you don't check whether this object exists or not. If you have a try/catch, you can catch this case and fail the test gracefully. if you don't have it, you will see a run time exception and the test will crash in not a graceful way.

Comment: Given the informality of the rest of the code in the question I assumed the line `Catch (exception ex)` was also informal. Generally in a C# program you should never catch all exceptions, you should only catch those you want to deal with. Coded UI tests use the `Assert.XXX()` methods to check things and to report failures. The whole idea of exceptions is to report exceptional events and let higher level code handle it. In the *object ... doesn't exist* case you mention, catching the exception and throwing your own graceful exception loses stack trace data hindering fault resolution.