# Calling A test method from a test method in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am merging the test cases on the basis of USERSTORY. 
    given is the example of the merged test cases.
    The WorkItem's are the Test Case ID's of the test cases which is being merged.
    Using Coded UI in windows.

```
  [TestMethod()]
        [TestCategory("Assessment"), TestCategory("US6540")]
        [Priority(2)]
        [WorkItem(16178), WorkItem(16180), WorkItem(16182), WorkItem(16183)]
        [Owner("...")]

        public void VerifyThatTeacherWillViewAllUnitsPresentinSectionFromAssessmentManagerPage()
        {
            try
            {
                Login login = Login.GetLogin("AssessmentTeacher");
                TaskInfo taskInfo = login.GetTaskInfo("ELA", "Assessment");
                NavigationCommonMethods.LoginApp(login);
                String[] UnitStatus = AssessmentCommonMethods.LoadUnitStatusFromAdditionalInfo(login);
                AssessmentCommonMethods.ClickAssessmentInDashBoard(UnitStatus[4]);
                Assert.IsTrue(AssessmentCommonMethods.VerifyListOfAllTheItemsAvailableinUnitTitleDropDown(), "All Units not Present in  Section in Assessment Manager Page");
                //16178
                //VerifyThatTeacherWillViewAllUnitsPresentinSectionFromAssessmentManagerPage

                AutomationAgent.Click(100, 100);
                AssessmentCommonMethods.AssessmentUnitSelection(10);
                Assert.IsTrue(AssessmentCommonMethods.VerifyUserIsNavigatedToUnit(10), "User is not navigated to correct unit");
                //16180
                //VerifyThatUnitDisplayIsClickable

                AssessmentCommonMethods.OpenUnitSelectionDropDown();
                Assert.IsTrue(AssessmentCommonMethods.VerifyAssessmentUnitSelection(10), "Assessment unit selection drop down not opened");
                AutomationAgent.Click(100, 100);
                Assert.IsFalse(AssessmentCommonMethods.VerifyAssessmentUnitSelection(10), "Assessment unit selection drop down opened");
                //16182
                //VerifyThattheUnitDropDownCanBeDismissedByTappingAnywhereOnThePage

                AssessmentCommonMethods.ClickBackButtonInAssessmentOverview();
                Assert.IsTrue(DashboardCommonMethods.VerifyUserIsOnDashBoard(), "User is not moved back on dashboard");
                //16183
                //VerifyBackButtonFunctionalityDisplayedOnUnitDisplayBar
                NavigationCommonMethods.Logout();
            }
            catch (AssertFailedException Ex)
            {
                string msg = Ex.Message;
                Logger.InsertExceptionMessage(msg);
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string msg = Ex.Message;
                Logger.InsertExceptionMessage(msg);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I want to make sure that when one of the test case got fail then it should return it test cases id with the pass or fail status.As you can see the test case ID's are commented where the particular verification is done.
Lets suppose the very first Assertion statement get true then it should return the test cases id in the report which is made by the visual studio.
And the after that the next assertion statement get failed then the report should comprise of the passed test cases id and the rest failed test cases id's.

Comment: First, I would trim down the length of that method name.

Comment: There are several questions here on Stackoverflow that discuss getting the results of all the assertions in a test. Some variation on them may help. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755899/coded-ui-continue-the-test-run-in-spite-of-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957368/how-to-use-multiple-assert-in-a-test and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011305/coded-ui-continue-on-failure-assertions

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to have as result of a test run. A list of failed and passed checks with WorkItem IDs? Or you want to continue the test run even if one of the asserts failed (providing the waorkitem id in the report)?

Comment: Firstly, I want to have the list of the passed and failed test cases..To be precise if the code run from the starting and if inbetween something get failed than the test case IDs which are already passed should be generated as a report.